# Notification Center Notifications - is there are way to be notified when NC is pulled down?

Tags: iphone, notificationcenter

Is there a notification I can listen for to be notified when a user pulls down the Notification Center? Not that I want to be all ironic and get an `NSNotification` about Notification Center through `NSNotificationCenter`, it actually could be useful. I'm thinking Evernote Peek-style studying, for iPhone.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific notification for it, but the standard UIApplication stuff should be called (applicationWillResignActive: / UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification).